# AS3 Error 1063 - with (seemingly) correct number of Arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, argument-error

So I've been toying with the idea of building a game, and at this point I'm just trying to get a basic framework down for a tile-based over-world, like in Pokemon or others.

The issue I'm having now is an absurd one; after fixing several other errors I'm still getting ArgumentError #1063 in two different places, and in both cases I pass the right amount of arguments in (both are constructors) and the error tells me I passed in 0.

Here's pertinent code for the first one:

```
public function Main()
    {

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, act, false, 0, true);
        key = new KeyObject(stage);

        overWorld = new Map(stage);
        stage.addChild(overWorld);

    }
```

(`overWorld` is a `Map` var, declared above with `public var overWorld:Map;`)

and:

```
public function Map(stageRef:Stage)
    {
        key2 = new KeyObject(stageRef);
        currentMap = MapArrays.testMap;

        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        initializeTiles();
    }
```

I'm calling the `Map()` constructor with the `stage` reference that it needs, and it's spitting out this as the error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Map(). Expected 1, got 0.
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at Main()
```

In addition, that `initializeTiles()` function holds the second of these two errors. Here's the code for that:

```
public function initializeTiles()
    {           

        for(var i:int = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            for(var j:int = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                var temp:String = ("tile"+i+"_"+j);
                this[temp] = new Tile(currentMap, (i+10), (j+10), (i * 30), (j * 30))
            }
        }

    }
```

and the `Tile()` constructor:

```
public function Tile(mapArr:Array, inX:int, inY:int, xpos:int, ypos:int)
    {

        mapArray = mapArr;
        arrX = inX;
        arrY = inY;
        x = xpos;
        y = ypos;
        determineTile();

    }
```

This is the error that spits out (500 times, 20x25):

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Tile(). Expected 5, got 0.
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at Map()
at Main()
```

Just to explain some, `mapArr`/`mapArray`/`currentMap` are Arrays of ints that describe the active mapset, `inX`/`arrX` is the `x` location of a given tile within the map (`inY`/`arrY` is of course the `y` location), and `xpos` and `ypos` are just where the tile sits on the screen (each tile is 30px by 30px). `determineTile()` just looks up the int `mapArray[arrX][arrY]` and changes the tile's attributes and image accordingly. `MapArrays` is a `public dynamic class` I created and imported in the `Map` class with `import MapArrays;`

Anyways, any help with this issue would be much appreciated. I can edit to post more code if someone thinks there may be an issue somewhere else, but these are the only places the constructors are called and the first 501 errors in my output (there are a few more, but they are **because** these constructors failed as they are null reference errors). I've been stuck here for a hefty chunk of time tweaking things slightly and nothing has worked thus far, and I don't see anywhere else where someone is getting this error while using the right amount of arguments.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any `Tile` and / or `Map` instances placed on the stage? If you do, the Flash runtime cannot instantiate those because you only have a single constructor that takes 5 parameters.

Comment: @xxbbcc Interesting. I didn't even think about that, but yes I did. I had both. Although I was considering deleting them anyways, but I never went through with it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad this helped. I added my comment as an answer, if you don't mind, vote for it & accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any `Tile` or `Map` instances placed on the stage, those instances would be instantiated by Flash at run-time by calling the constructor (just like when you create an instance of `Tile` by calling `new Tile(...)`.

Since your `Tile` and `Map` classes have custom constructors (that take parameters), Flash cannot create an instance of those display objects because it doesn't know what to pass as input parameters to the constructor - this is why you get the error.

Usually it's best not to put anything on the stage that has code backing it up - just create those instances from code and add them to the stage at run-time. This is extra work but it keeps your setup cleaner.